# Changing mouse cursor in a QObject - QGraphicsItem inherited class

Tags: qt, nested

I would like to change my mouse cursor when it is in a graphics item (MyCircle inherits from `QObject` and `QGraphicsItem`). 
Had my class inherited from `QWidget`, I would have reimplemented `enterEvent()` and `leaveEvent()` and use it as follows :

```
MyCircle::MyCircle(QObject *parent)
    : QWidget(parent), QGraphicsItem() // But I can't
{
    rect = QRect(-100,-100,200,200);
    connect(this,SIGNAL(mouseEntered()),this,SLOT(in()));
    connect(this,SIGNAL(mouseLeft()),this,SLOT(out()));
}

void MyCircle::in()
{
    QApplication::setOverrideCursor(Qt::PointingHandCursor);
}

void MyCircle::out()
{
    QApplication::setOverrideCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor);
}

void MyCircle::enterEvent(QEvent *)
{
    emit mouseEntered();
}

void MyCircle::leaveEvent(QEvent *)
{
    emit mouseLeft();
}
```

Unfortunately, I need to animate that circle (it's a button actually), so I need QObject, is there an easy way to change the cursor ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably use [hover events](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#setAcceptHoverEvents).

In your class constructor make sure you do...

```
setAcceptHoverEvents(true);
```

Then override [`hoverEnterEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#hoverEnterEvent) and [`hoverLeaveEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#hoverLeaveEvent).

```
virtual void hoverEnterEvent (QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *event) override
{
  QGraphicsItem::hoverEnterEvent(event);
  QApplication::setOverrideCursor(Qt::PointingHandCursor);
}

virtual void hoverLeaveEvent (QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *event) override
{
  QGraphicsItem::hoverLeaveEvent(event);
  QApplication::setOverrideCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor);
}
```

As a side note: do you actually inherit from both `QObject` *and* `QGraphicsItem`?  If so, you could probably achieve the same goal by simply inheriting from [`QGraphicsObject`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsobject.html).

**Edit 1:**  In answer to...

> I have the pointing hand icone in my whole bounding rect, how can I
>   reduce the area only to my drawing (in this case a circle) ?

Override [`QGraphicsItem::shape`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#shape) to return a `QPainterPath` representing the *actual* shape...

```
virtual QPainterPath shape () const override
{
  QPainterPath path;

  /*
   * Update path to represent the area in which you want
   * the mouse pointer to change.  This will probably be
   * based on the code in your 'paint' method.
   */
  return(path);
}
```

Now override [`QGraphicsItem::hoverMoveEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#hoverMoveEvent) to make use of the `shape` method...

```
virtual void hoverMoveEvent (QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *event) override
{
  QGraphicsItem::hoverMoveEvent(event);
  if (shape().contains(event->pos())) {
    QApplication::setOverrideCursor(Qt::PointingHandCursor);
  } else {
    QApplication::setOverrideCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor);
  }
}
```

The above could, obviously, have an impact on performance depending on the complexity of the shape drawn and, hence, the `QPainterPath`.

(Note: rather than using `QGraphicsItem::shape` you could do a similar thing with [`QGraphicsItem::opaque`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#opaqueArea) instead.)

Comment: This looks very smooth, but I have the "nested error" : incomplete type 'QApplication' used in nested name'.
You're right, I could do that ! (doesn't solve the issue thought)

Comment: If the code I've shown results in an incomplete type error for `QApplication` then I think the code shown in your question should as well -- right?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: I wrote the above code to explain what I wanted, knowing that it would'nt work (since 'enterEvent()' and 'leaveEvent' both belong to 'QWidget' class), but as a matter of fact, I tried, and yes I have the same error. May be I should give my whole code ? It works without the 'hover...' implementation. Nevertheless, I should point out that 'paint()', 'boundingRect()' and 'mousePressEvent()' are also implemented.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused as to what works and what doesn't.  If you fix the incomplete type error in my answer by adding `#include <QApplication>` does it then behave as expected?  If not, please edit your question to provide more information.

Comment: I'm confused too ... I added #include <QApplication>, and well it worked. But why ? It was already included in my main ? I must miss something sorry ! 
Thank you anyway !
(Bonus ?) Also, it works fine, but (as expected I have to admit), I have the pointing hand icone in my whole bounding rect, how can I reduce the area only to my drawing (in this case a circle) ?

Comment: See **Edit 1** in my answer.

Comment: Answer to Edit 1 : I feel ashamed to coming back with another error, but I can't find any solution. The compiler complains that my code includes/declare twice 'QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent' after I changed the 'hoverEnterEvent end 'hoverLeaveEvent' solution with the new greedy but more precise one. More precisly it says :'invalid use of incomplete type :class QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent' [...] 'forward declaration of : QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent'. Why does it complain with this solution but not with the previous one ?
Edit : Sorry I don't know how to write code here ... Oh I'm too old to go on forums

Comment: In general, if you get a compilation error of the type "use of incomplete type `foo`" it means the compiler has only seen a forward declaration.  You need to `#include` the header that defines the type -- in this case `#include <QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent>`.  The original answer didn't actually reference the `QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent` interface in any way and so the forward declaration was sufficient.

Comment: Thank you so much, you nailed it !

[To go further] ... I have several classes, that draw different object. I'm wondering why I get the pointingHand cursor only for one of them ... (the boundingRect and so the click reaction works fine with all my object). Plus, I also used a QPushButton designed with css, problem is, the setCursor fonction doesn't work (because of the css ?), so is there a way to do it in this case ?
(Perhaps I should make an other post

Comment: Edit for thr QPushButton: The icone change when the mouse is hovering the button if it didn't hovered the central (MyCircle) button before. Afterwards the cursor stays in the arrow size when hovering the button, and switch to pointingHand when hovering MyCircle

Answer (score 4):

`QGraphicsItem` already has a method for changing the cursor, so you don't need to manually play around with hover events:

```
QGraphicsItem::setCursor(const QCursor &cursor)
```

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#setCursor

PS: The dual inheritance of `QWidget` and `QGraphicsItem` you do is also a bad idea, only inherit from `QGraphicsItem`.